# javascript stop autolog-in in firefox and chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome, firefox, authentication

I'm trying to implement logout functionality in asp.net (NTLM auth).
Session.Abandon works fine but with Firefox of Chrome if user do not close browser window - browser automatically log him in with previous credentials. Only IE properly always asks for new credentials.

After all browser windows are closed, browser properly asks for user and password with "Authentication required" window.

Tried to clear cookies with

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", ".force_logout_offer_login_mozilla", true, "logout", "logout");
```

or

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", '<DOMAIN>?&timeSpan=' + (new Date().getTime().toString()), true, "logout", "logout");
```

The cookie is cleared, .net creates new session objects but Firefox and chrome login user "transparently" again.

The second version on IE asks for credentials for "logout" user, but on Firefox it just log-in with previously sent values.

Is there any way to stop this behavior? It seems like serious security problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Windows Challenge/Response (NTLM) is the authentication protocol used on **networks** that include systems running the Windows operating system and on stand-alone systems.

It's not a serious security problem *unless* you don't trust the people logging into your network domain.

With Windows Authentication, you cannot invalidate the user's session unless they log out of the network (i.e. their computer) or they close the browser. There may be workarounds with IE, but it won't work in other browsers because it's not the their problem. They are simply following the authentication practice that was set up.

Once a user is verified by the network, ASP.NET will pass their credentials "transparently" through to a Windows Authenticated web application without prompt. Even if you managed to invalidate the session via code, they can just hit the back button and continue where they left off.

If you want to log users out, you should select a different authentication mechanism like Basic or Forms Authentication. This is typically the one requirement users do not understand about Windows Authenticated web apps who clamor for a Logoff button.